# Add arguements bash

Tags: bash, recursion, find, arguments

Sup mates,
Building a "find" command in bash
Currently have it working when a directory is passed but if it isn't passed, running "find" is suppose to default to "find ./"

What occurs with my code is that my recursion function (a func that adds all items in its file tree) works with a for loop that uses $@

```
recurse(){
oldIFS=$IFS
     IFS=$'\n'
     for f in $@
         do
             list="`echo -e "$list\n$PWD/${f}"`"
             if [[ -d "${f}" ]]
                 then 
                     cd "${f}"
                     recurse $(ls -1 ".")
                     cd ..
             fi      
     done   
     IFS=$oldIFS
}
```

So is there a way to add a command line argument so i keep the code the same
or
How do i create a variable that holds $@ so i can use that in the for loop above
and then i can just set that variable to "./" if i detect $# == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array, to match the array in `$@`.

```
args=("$@")
if (( ${#args[@]} == 0 ))
then
  args=(./)
fi

for f in "${args[@]}"
do
   ...
done
```